# How to export/copy a shapefile from a hosted feature layer from ArcGIS online using ArcPy (Python 3.x) and ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I am rewriting a 2.x script for compatibility with ArcGIS Pro and Python 3.x. My question is, how do I export a shapefile from a hosted feature layer from ArcGIS online using ArcPy (Python 3.x) and ArcGIS Pro?

The working python 2.x script written for ArcGIS Desktop does it this way:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("path_to_mxd_containing_online_layer.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0] 

### exporting the data to a local TEMP layer
inspector_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "name_of_layer_in_mxd", df)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer == True:
        d = lyr.name.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        file_name = d + ".shp"
        dest1 = os.path.join(wkspce, file_name)
        try:
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr, dest1)
        except:
            pass
```

I was thinking of creating an aprx project file that contained a map with the layer in it, as that seems the closest to the original script. This is one way of writing it:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("G:\\Code Enforcement\\ACD Admin Operations\\GIS\\Operations\\Mapping\\Automation\\Auto_District_Mapping_PRO\\Auto_District_Mapping_PRO.aprx")
m = aprx.listMaps("name_of_map")
inspector_layer = m.listLayers('name_of_layer')

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inspector_layer, r"C:\\testfolder\\name_of_layer.shp")
```

I am getting the following error: 'list' object has no attribute 'listLayers' on the line that reads `inspector_layer = m.listLayers('name_of_layer')`, hence my question of how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using addDataFromPath function can add hosted feature layers using the service url.

The code looks like: 
`inspector_layer = m.addDataFromPath('service_url_for_hosted_feature_layer')`